# Doctrine 2 limit IN subquery

Tags: doctrine-orm, subquery, limit, dql

I'm trying to use a subquery in a IN statement in Doctrine2.

Here's what the raw SQL query should look like :

```
SELECT * FROM license 
WHERE id 
IN (SELECT id 
    FROM license 
    WHERE subscription = x 
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

What I want to do is display the 5 last results ordered by name, so I have to first query the last 5 results and then order by name in the main query.

The problem is that I can't seem to LIMIT the inner query.

Here's my current code :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
$qb->select('l.id');
$qb = $this->whereSubscriptionId($qb, $subscription_id);
$qb = $this->offsetLimitOrder($qb, 0, 5, 'deliveryDatetime desc');

//Second Query, adds the "order by X"
$qb2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('l2');
$qb2->add('where', $qb2->expr()->in('l2.id', $qb->getQuery()->getDQL()));
if(isset($order)){
    $order = explode(' ', $order);
    $qb2->addOrderBy('l2.'.$order[0], $order[1]);
 }

 return $qb2->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

As you can see, I create my first query, I order and limit it (via a custom method) and then I try to use it in the second query.

However, it seems that the LIMIT is not part of the DQL statement because when I var_dump the first query's DQL, the LIMIT is absent, which means that it's completly ignored when I run $qb2->getQuery()->getResult();

I made it work by launching the first query and manually inputing the results in the second one, but it's ugly.

Any idea on how to do it properly ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you use QueryBuilder's setMaxResults function?

Comment: yes, you could create 2 query builders, one for the IN subselect, and one for the global DQL. in the first one, use `setMaxResults`.

Comment: Seems that main reason for limit not included in DQL is caching - http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-885

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068947/subquery-with-limit-in-doctrine could be a solution

Comment: See my answer on this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46663949/146738

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately Doctrine does not support limit on nested queries. Even if you use 2 QueryBuilders and setMaxResults() on the inner QueryBuilder, it will simply be ignored.

The only way to do this at this time is to run 2 individual queries.

Comment: This is really unfortunate. I was looking at my code for an hour trying to figure out what's wrong. Doctrine could've at least throw an exception saying that it's unsupported.

Comment: Marking this as answer because while it didn't help, it did confirm my doubts that it just can't be done.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068947/subquery-with-limit-in-doctrine could be a solution